# Review suggestion - after seven years?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, old-questions

I just received a comment for one of my answers that it was considered a "low-quality" link-only response on an answer I posted over seven years ago.

While I completely agree with the point made that links might get invalid and the answer should include the most important aspects directly, I think it's not really useful to review answers which are that old.

I think with technology changing so fast, after such a long time, it wouldn't make any sense to go back and now change the answer to include the link content (if I wrote the answer today, I would definitely do that!) as it might be obsolete by now.

So what's the point in doing reviews for answers older than let's say 3-5 years?
I think it should be clear to everyone, that those might not be up-to-date anyway.

The post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850179/232175

Comment: Since you seem to be new in meta, please do dot worry about down-votes here. They do not affect your account or rep, and they are casted much more liberally than in the main site. Many times they can be casted to signal disagreement with a question's premise.

Comment: You might have missed the contractual obligation of posting that answer 7 years ago, you do get to maintain it for the rest of your natural life.  He couldn't even be bothered to DV the post, reviewing like that merely chases contributors away.

Comment: @Hans, in the LQP review queue you are not presented with buttons to vote. I gather that the omission is intentional.

Comment: Audits were designed to prevent reviewers from doing everything from the review page.  They don't work that well, a little bit helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not about the answer not being up-to-date. It's about the answer being in a format that's not fit for Stack Overflow.

In my opinion, old link-only answers should be removed. Links die, get replaced by other sites, etc. Also, we have [the broken windows theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory): people use very old posts to justify their current actions. We can't close or lock old answers, but we can remove them through review.

This is a special case because it's a link to an SO post, so it's not as bad. But it still shouldn't be there. Either it's a comment asking for clarification: *Are you running your WPF application as a 64-bit application?*, or it's indicating that a different post holds the current answer, and then the question should be marked as a duplicate.

In conclusion, your answer doesn't hold real value, and while it has been posted a long time ago, we should enforce the current quality standard for old answers, since we don't have a lot of other options for them.

To save people from notifications on old posts, only link-only reviews generate such a notification, since the OP might be able to adjust and salvage the answer by including the linked content, which is all good in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have just deleted my answer to "keep the windows neat and tidy" so to say :-) I agree, a comment would have been a much better choice.

Answer (score 16):

#### When a user flags a post, they should not have to check how old it is.

They should only consider if it's up to our standards or not. Age is not really relevant.

Would you propose locking old posts completely, because they are old? So they can't be voted on anymore? The whole idea is that content will be moderated as time goes on and the post gets more exposure.

The point of reviewing old posts is the same than when reviewing newer posts: **to keep the site's content curated and the quality as high as possible**.